# Challenges with Carnets app Can’t install Library for statsmodel and SciPy (jupyter on Ipad Pro)

Tags: python, ipad, jupyter

I’m using this amazing app Carnets on IPad-Pro.

I’ve challenge installing above two library on IPad. I get following error
[image: error while install statmodels on IPad Pro]

Please help.